# why don't asyncio call_later() not work in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Here is my code in python3.6

```
import asyncio
import time

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("A init")
        print("actvating1")
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.asyncFunc(loop))
        print("actvating2")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("actvating3")
        print("end")
        loop.close()
    def compute_pi(self):
        print("3.14???")

    async def asyncFunc(self,loop):
        loop.call_later(1, self.compute_pi, None)



if __name__== "__main__":
    a = A()
```

result

```
A init
actvating1
actvating2
actvating3
end
```

expected result

```
A init
actvating1
actvating2
3.14???
actvating3
end
```

i want compute_pi(self) function work.
PyCharm did't print error or warning.
What is the key to my miss understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the second process running `compute_pi` is dead by the time you get to sleep. This is since you use `call_later` - `asyncFunc` keeps running after the call and returns immediately since it is asynchronous. This

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Actvating")
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.asyncFunc(loop))
        print("end")
        loop.close()

    def compute_pi(self):
        print("3.14???")

    async def asyncFunc(self,loop):
        print("Called")
        loop.call_later(1, self.compute_pi)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

if __name__== "__main__":
    a = A()
```

prints `3.14`. If you remove the `sleep`, or make the time to short, it will not - the process is stopped, so you do not get to `call_later` in time.  That is why sleeping outside of the `run_until_complete` will not work, no matter the waiting period. You have to keep the loop itself alive until the callback.

Comment: I suggest changing `time.sleep(2)` to `await asyncio.sleep(2)`. Using `time.sleep()` in an asyncio coroutine or callback is an anti-pattern because it blocks the event loop from making progress during the sleep.

Comment: Thanks, it's otherwise a good explanation of what's going on.